# Replacing substring but skipping previous occurance

Tags: python

I have a long string that may contain multiple same sub-strings. I would like to extract certain sub-strings by using regex. Then, for each extracted sub-string, I want to append [i] and replace the original one.

By using Regex, I extracted ['df.Libor3m','df.Libor3m_lag1','df.Libor3m_lag1']. However, when I tried to add [i] to each item, the first 'df.Libor3m_lag1' in string is replaced twice.

```
function_text_MD='0.11*(np.maximum(df.Libor3m,0.9)-np.maximum(df.Libor3m_lag1,0.9))+0.7*np.maximum(df.Libor3m_lag1,0.9)'

read_var = re.findall(r"df.[\w+][^\W]+",function_text_MD)

for var_name in read_var:
  function_text_MD.find(var_name)
  new_var_name = var_name+'[i]'
  function_text_MD=function_text_MD.replace(var_name,new_var_name,1)
```

So I got **'0.11*(np.maximum(df.Libor3m[i],0.9)-np.maximum(df.Libor3m_lag1[i][i],0.9))+0.7*np.maximum(df.Libor3m_lag1,0.9)'**.

df.Libor3m_lag1[i][i] was added [i] twice.

What I want to get:
**'0.11*(np.maximum(df.Libor3m[i],0.9)-np.maximum(df.Libor3m_lag1[i],0.9))+0.7*np.maximum(df.Libor3m_lag1[i],0.9)'**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Better use "re.sub" to find and replace in one operation. The used "str.replace" just finds the first occurrence and replaces that.

Comment: By the way: The calling of "str.find" is useless if the return value isn't processed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code.

```
    import re
    function_text_MD='0.11*(np.maximum(df.Libor3m,0.9)-np.maximum(df.Libor3m_lag1,0.9))+0.7*np.maximum(df.Libor3m_lag1,0.9)'
    read_var = re.findall(r"df.[\w+][^\W]+",function_text_MD)
    for var_name in read_var:
        function_text_MD = function_text_MD.replace(var_name,var_name+'[i]')
    print(function_text_MD)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
t = "0.11*(np.maximum(df.Libor3m,0.9)-np.maximum(df.Libor3m_lag1,0.9))+0.7*np.maximum(df.Libor3m_lag1,0.9)"
p = re.split("(?<=df\.)[a-zA-Z_0-9]+", t)
s = re.findall("(?<=df\.)[a-zA-Z_0-9]+", t)
s = [x+"[i]" for x in s]
result = "".join([p[0],s[0],p[1],s[1],p[2],s[2]])
```

use the regular expression to split string first.
use the same regular expression to find the spliters 
change the spliters to what you want
put the 2 list together and join.

Comment: Find another way for last step.

from itertools import chain

r = list(chain(*zip(p,s)))
result = ".".join(r)